# Why does 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sumlist' referenced before assignment' appear even when it is in the function

Tags: python

I am attemtping project euler question 8.  I have created a function that, I think, finds the sum of the first 13 numbers then moves on to the 2nd-14th numbers and so on.

```
def get_sum(list):
  while len(list) <= 987:
    sumlist = []
    count = 0
    value = sum(list[0+count:13+count])
    sumlist.append(value)
    count += 1
  return max(sumlist)
mylist = str(7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450)
print(get_sum(mylist))
```

It displays this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "python", line 12, in <module>
 File "python", line 8, in get_sum
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sumlist' referenced before assignment
```

I am quite new to python so apologies if this simple.
Please help.

Comment: If the length of the string is greater than  987 at the start then you never enter the `while` loop. Beyond that, I find it hard to believe you want every single object inside the `while` loop to be completely reset on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help